# Where can we specify the Auth Type for API resource in WSO2 AM 1.7

Tags: oauth, wso2, swagger, swagger-ui, wso2-api-manager

Where can we specify the Auth Type for API resource in WSO2 AM 1.7

in the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Adding+Documentation+Using+Swagger it says that it can be defined from adding the resource but those options are completely different.

[image: what I have on AM 1.7]

[image: what documentation says]

Answer (score 0):

Auth types that are available are shown in the Auth Type column of API Resources section. These are the Auth Types available for the Resource Owner OAuth grant type. You cannot change these Auth types as they are based on the OAuth Spec.